# Linear optimization using binary variables R

Tags: r, optimization, binary

I'm looking at a firm, which can produce an output over four hours, and has sold and output S0 which indicates the average sold output. I'm looking to minimize the difference between the produced and the sold output. 
We have a start value, and the catch is that if the previous production is 100 or over, we can increase or decrease the next by 10, and if not only by 5.

i'm using lpSolveAPI in R, and my codes is as follows:

```
library(lpSolveAPI)
S0=90
x=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)
error=make.lp(0,11)
lp.control(error, sense="min")
set.objfn(error,x)
set.type(error, 7:10, "binary")

x=rep(0,11)
for (i in 1:4){
x[i]=1
x[5]=-4
}
add.constraint(error, x, "=",0)
x=rep(0,11)
#error
x[5]=1
x[6]=-1
add.constraint(error, x, "=",S0)
x=rep(0,11)
#maximum increase 
for (i in 1:3){
for (j in 7:10){´
x[i+1]=1
x[i]=-1
x[j]=-5
add.constraint(error, x, "<=", 5)
x[i]=0
x[i+1]=0
x[j]=0}}
#maximum decrease 
for (i in 1:3){
for (j in 7:10){
x[i]=-1
x[i+1]=1
x[j]=5
add.constraint(error, x, ">=", -5)
x[i]=0
x[i+1]=0
x[j]=0
}}
for (i in 1:3){
for (j in 7:10){
x[i]=1
x[j]=-100
add.constraint(error, x, ">=", 0)
x[i]=0
x[j]=0}}
#STARTING VALUE 
x[1]=1
add.constraint(error, x, "=", 110)
x=rep(0:11)
solve(error)
get.objective(error)
get.variables(error)
```

My question is that when i get the results i get.

```
0
10
110 100 100  90 100  10   1   1   1   1   0
```

so a production of 110, 100, 100 and 90 in hour 1,2,3 and 4. This gives an average production of 100 and an error of 10. Why does it produce 100 in hour 3, when it could decrease to 90, and afTer that 85, which would produce an average of 96.25 and an error of 6.25.

Comment: Hm, as interesting and well presented as this question is, I fail to see the coding issue with it. The problem may be the optimization algorithm used by the package.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for a better package, that could do the trick?